# Understanding Cache Keys, Index, Partition and Affinity w.r.t reads and writes

Tags: ignite, partition, gridgain, affinity

I am new to Apache Ignite and come from a Data Warehousing background. 
So pardon me if I try to relate to Ignite through DBMS jargon. 
I have gone through forums but I am still unclear about some of the basics.

I also would like specific answers to the scenario I have posted later.

1.) CacheMode=PARTITIONED
   a.) When a cache is declared as partitioned, does the data get equally 
       partitioned across all nodes by default?

b.) Is there an option to provide a "partition key" based on which the data
       would be distributed across the nodes? Is this what we call the Affinity
       Key?

c.) How is partitioning different from affinity and can a cache have both 
       partition and affinity key?

2.) Affinity Concept
With an Affinity Key defined, when I load data (using loadCache()) into   a partitioned cache, will the source rows be sent to the node they belong to or all the nodes on the cluster?

3.) If I create one index on the cache, does it by default become the partition/
affinity key as well? In such a scenario, how is a partition different from    index?

***SCNEARIO DESCRIPTION***

I want to load data from a persistent layer into a Staging Cache (assume ~2B) using loadCache(). The cache resides on a 4 node cluster. 
a.) How to load data such that each node has to process only 0.5B records? 
    Is is by using Partitioned Cache mode and defining an Affinity Key?

Then I want to read transactions from the Staging Cache in TRANSACTIONAL atomicity mode, lookup a Target Cache and do some operations.

b.) When I do the lookup on Target Cache, how can I ensure that the lookup is happening only on the node where the data resides and not do lookup on all the nodes on which Target Cache resides? 
Would that be using the AffinityKeyMapper API? If yes, how?

c.) Lets say I wanted to do a lookup on a key other than Affinity Key column, can creating an index on the lookup column help? Would I end up scanning all nodes in that case?

**Staging Cache** 
CustomerID 
CustomerEmail 
CustomerPhone

**Target Cache** 
Seq_Num 
CustomerID 
CustomerEmail 
CustomerPhone 
StartDate 
EndDate

Answer (score 0):

This is answered on Apache Ignite users forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Understanding-Cache-Key-Indexes-Partition-and-Affinity-td11212.html

---

1. Ignite uses AffinityFunction [1] for data distribution. AF implements two mappings: key->partition and partition->node.
   Key->Partition mapping is definitely map entry to partition. It doesn't bother of backups, but data collocation\distribution over partitions.
   Usually, entry key (actually it's hashcode) is used to calculate partition entry belongs to. 
   But you can use AffinityKey [2] that would be use instead to manage data collocation. See also 'org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.AffinityKey' javadoc.

Partition->Node mapping determines primary and backup nodes for partition. It doesn't bother of data collocation, but backups and partition distribution among nodes

Cache.loadCache just makes all nodes to call localLoadCache method. Which calls CacheStore.loadCache. So, each of grid nodes will load all the data from cache store and then discard data that is not local for the node.

2. Same data may resides on several nodes if you use a backups. AffinityKey should be a part of entry key and if AffinityKey mapping is configured then AffinityKey will be used instead of entry key for entry->partition mapping 
   and AffinityKey will be passed to AffinityFunction.
3. Indexes always resides on same node with the data.

a. To achieve this you should implement CacheStore.loadCache method to load data for certain partitions. E.g. you can store partitionID for each row in database.
However, if you change AF or partitions numbers you should update partitionID for entries in database as well.

The other way. If it is posible, you can load all the data in single node and then add other nodes to the grid. Data will rebalanced over nodes automatically.

b. AffinityKey is always used if it is as it shoud be part of entry key. So, lookup will always be happening on the node where the data resides.

c. I can't understand the question. Would you please clarify if it still is actual?

Comment: Possible to cross-post to here? Nabble is considered a "social network" in many corporate environments and is blocked therefore.

Comment: @bobah sorry for the late update, but I have attempted to edit the answer to include the response from the hyperlink